# Can I dynamically set field names in Django orm query?

Tags: django, django-views

Can I dynamically set field names in Django view?

I want this code

```
CategoryNick.objects.get(author=self.request.user).get(field=slug)
```

but error is occured

```
AttributeError: 'CategoryNick' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Is there a good way to solve this problem?

if you know solution thank you for let me know

total code

```
    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(type(self), self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts_without_category'] = MyShortCut.objects.filter(category=None,author=self.request.user).count()
        context['category_list'] = Category.objects.all()

        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        if slug == '_none':
            context['category'] = 'no_category'
        else:
            category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
            context['category'] = category
            context['category_nick'] = CategoryNick.objects.get(author=self.request.user).get(field=slug)

        return context
```

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to dynamically set the field name of the query set to get the field value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing like this `CategoryNick.objects.get(author=self.request.user).get(field=slug)` you can do like this `CategoryNick.objects.get(author=self.request.user, field=slug)`

Comment: It's like a simple, easy-to-understand grammar.
Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the `field` of the object, you can use [**`.values_list(..., flat=True)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) here, like:

```
CategoryNick.objects.values_list('slug', flat=True).get(author=self.request.user)
```

So here you will retrieve the `slug` value for that `CategoryNick`. If you use `'pk'` instead, you will get the primary key.

It is however a bit "odd" to just query for a given field name.

Comment: I did not know there was such a good feature in Django. Thanks again for letting me know.

Comment: Thank you very much
It works well.
I'll read the documentation you provided.
Thank you